# How to synchronize threads in Messages on Mac and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, messages

I actually receive iMessages on a Mac and an iPhone, and I could say that they are correctly synchronized on **reception**.

Now from time to time, as everybody I have a huge volume of old iMessages
to delete. Since I don't want to make masive destruction I usually perform
this task on my Mac where it is much more easy and faster. The risk of
selection errors is also much lower.

For example I recently deleted a few hundreds iMassages on one thread
`Alice` on my Mac.

And I wasen't able to find any easy way to get the same thread `Alice` cleaned accordingly on my iPhone.

I imagined a few seconds to make these threads scroll in parallel on my
Mac and my iPhone and delete manually the one already deleted on my Mac.
But after 2 minutes of this boring task I understood this can't be
the intelligent way.

I searched on my preffered search engine for half an hour to find many
discussions on the synchronization on **reception**, but none about synchronization on **deletion**.

What is the best method to achieve this synchronization of **deletion**
between Messages on a Mac and an iPhone?
My purpose is to obtain a real thread synchronization between devices.

The Mac versions I am running and interested in are:

- Yosemite
- El Capitan

the iPhone ones are:

- 9.3
- 10.2